# django this is not working.. image is not showing in the page

Tags: css, django

I am trying to make simple webpage but I am unable to load the image in the page

```
<div class="background_image" style="background-image:url({% static 'static/images/home_slider.jpg'%})"></div>
```

Comment: You already referred to static files once, so no need of including it in the URL too.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% load static %} 
<img src="{% static 'images/home_slider.jpg' %}" alt="Hi!" />
```

It may help you.